# How can i set optional parameter in the Mod Rewrite-Syntax?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm german and i'm sorry about my damn sucking englisch.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.php?admin=$1
```

here is an example.
so the result i want is for example the id within, but as an optional parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/id-(.*)$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$2
```

Here the id don't must set thats what i want :)

The Link example (i want that here is the same result):

www.exmple.com/admin/edit-user
www.exmple.com/admin/edit-user/id-1

the problem is: the rule take anytime the first way with only this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.php?admin=$1
```

can anybody help me ? :)

loving greetings m0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the order of your rules and don't forget the [L] flag at the end :

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/id-(.*)$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.php?admin=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try an optional capture group:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)(/id-(.*))?$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$3
```

If there's no id specified, then $3 will be blank and you'll just get a blank id rewritten:

```
index.php?admin=edit_user&id=
```

If it is specified, then you'll get the id too:

```
index.php?admin=edit_user&id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `.*` is too general as it matches an arbitrary length of arbitrary characters. A better expression would be `[^/]+` that matches only one ore more arbitrary characters except `/` (path segments separator).

So try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)$ index.php?admin=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/id-([^/]+)$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$2
```

For the second rule you could also replace the second `[^/]+` with `[1-9][0-9]*` that would match only integers greater than 0.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/id-([1-9][0-9]*)$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteRule /admin/([^/]*)/?(id-(.*))?$ index.php?admin=$1&id=$3
```